# Connect OpenVPN in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, openvpn

Is it possible to connect openVPN programmatically from the Chrome extension API? All I've found in Chrome extensions API docs are `chrome.proxy` and `chrome.socket`.

I belive it is possible to run external program using `NPAPI` and this extenral program will create nessesary openVPN connection.

**UPD:** It seems that OpenVPN have TCP/Socket management interface ( see http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html ) So it is rather easy to connect it from Chrome extension programmatically.

Comment: NPAPI could do it, but chrome has [announced](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) they are going to kill NPAPI support sometime in 2014. At this point, the only thing that can run an external program on Chrome is a protocol handler.

Comment: my guess is several "high profile" NPAPI plugins will get whitelisted, like Java and Silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@vcsjones is correct... the proper way would be with NPAPI or a protocol handler.  However, there is another method.

In the past, when I have needed to execute native code with a browser extension, I embed a small HTTP server into a native application that can be called from the browser extension.  This allows me to write whatever I need to, while the browser extension is nothing but a control for that native application.  You could then easily write something to control OpenVPN.

Comment: Aha, got it. So I can write simple python application that will listen on port and will connect any OpenVPN configuration I need on request. Very nice idea, thank you!

Comment: Hey, Brad. Seems OpenVPN have management interface; see UPD for my original question.

Comment: @Kirzilla You still need a go-between.  You won't be able to open a raw TCP socket from a browser extension.